# How to select different layout in Cake PHP Email template

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

This is below email code working file

```
$email = new CakeEmail('smtp');
$fromConfig = EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS;
$fromNameConfig = EMAIL_FROM_NAME;
$email->from(array( $fromConfig => $fromNameConfig));
$email->sender(array( $fromConfig => $fromNameConfig));
$email->to($this->data['Subscribe']['email']);
$email->subject('Newsletter Confirmation');
$email->template('subscribe');
$email->emailFormat('html');
```

my above code taking default.ctp layout file by default(app\View\Layouts\Emails\html\default.ctp), it's fine.

But my question is i have created a other fancy.ctp layout file(app\View\Layouts\Emails\html\fancy.ctp) not use default.ctp layout file

How to use this fancy.ctp layout file in Email

Comment: Use the template method per http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html _there is another parameter for the layout_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved issue myself......... Below my working code

```
$email = new CakeEmail('smtp');
$fromConfig = EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS;
$fromNameConfig = EMAIL_FROM_NAME;
$email->from(array( $fromConfig => $fromNameConfig));
$email->sender(array( $fromConfig => $fromNameConfig));
$email->to($this->data['Subscribe']['email']);
$email->subject('Newsletter Confirmation');
$email->template('subscribe','fancy');
$email->emailFormat('html');
```

Answer (score -1):

Please add below line

```
$email->layout('fancy');
```

Comment: Instead of burying the changes in a bunch of code it would have been enough to just post that one single line, wouldn't it? A few words of explanation wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: But i m getting error on that line undefined method CakeEmail::layout()

Comment: @vikamtyagi That's because there is no `layout()` method in `CakeEmail`, it's all done via `CakeEmail::template()`. Somehow I removed that hint from my comment in an edit...

Comment: @ndm wht's answer for it, could you explain it.

Comment: @vikamtyagi: here already explain for layout.Look at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#configurations